# Sending data to Firebase database from Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

I am very new in javascript and Firebase Database, and I cant quite comprehend how to send data to my database from it. I am sending data from an html document and I know how to record the information in to a variable, but now I want to send it to firebase and I dont know how to initialize the Firebase Database from Javascript. Thank you.

Comment: the firebase docs is a good place to search. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: I see that you are a very new user. New users are very important to us and we'd like to help you be more successful on this site. Please take a look at this [Help Article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking a good question that's likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use JavaScript SDK of Firebase.
Configure you app first.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

To read data:

```
firebase.database().ref('/list').once('value').then(function(data) {
  // ...
});
```

read this documentation for more details:

[Add Firebase to your JavaScript Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)